# How to make the `thead` of a `mdl-data-table` stay on screen

Tags: html-table, material-design-lite

Is there a way to make the `thead` section of a `mdl-data-table` stay on screen? when I scroll through table but disappear if no part of the table is visible.

I wonder if it is even possible with a page that does not use Material Design Lite.